# SQL ERROR When running query

Tags: oracle, select, join, syntax

I've been trying to execute below code, but it's not running. SQLFiddle gives

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'.'EO' AS 'EO','EF'.'AC' AS 'AC','EO''` at line 2

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

`SELECT DISTINCT
   'EO'.'EO' AS 'EO',
   'EF'.'AC' AS 'AC',
   'EO'.'WO' AS 'WO',
   'EO'.'WOF' AS 'WOF',
   'EF'.'PN_SN' AS 'PN_SN',
   'EC'.'CD' AS 'CD',
   'EF'.'PN' AS 'PN',
   'EO'.'EOC' AS 'EOC',
   'EO'.'STAT' AS 'STAT',
   'EF'.'OVRD' AS 'OVRD',
   'EF'.'SEL' AS 'SEL',
   'EF'.'ED' AS 'ED',
   'EF'.'SCHED' AS 'SCHED',
   'EF'.'SAD' AS 'SAD',
   'EF'.'SA' AS 'SA',
   'EO'.'EOD' AS 'EOD' 
    FROM
    EO,
    EC,
    EF 
    WHERE
    (
      'EO'.'EO' = 'EC'.'EO' 
    )
    AND 
    (
       'EF'.'PSN' = 'EC'.'PSN' 
    )
    AND 
    (
      'EO'.'WB' = 'Y' 
    )
    AND 
    (
      'EC'.'CONT' = 'W & B' 
     )
     ;
    SELECT
    'EC'.'RSTD' AS 'RSTD' 
    FROM EC RIGHT JOIN EF
      ON ( 'EF'.'EO' = 'EC'.'EO' ) 
      ON ( 'EF'.'AC' = 'EC'.'AC' ) 
      ON ( 'EF'.'PN' = 'EC'.'PN' ) 
      ON ( 'EF'.'PSN' = 'EC'.'PSN' )`

Comment: Make you mind up - Oracle or MySQL? Why do you have single quotes around object names?

Comment: You have this tagged as Oracle with a message referencing MySQL. If it is Oracle then supply the code you ran (the above code wont run in Oracle) and show us the Oracle error that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes - `'` - are for literals. Use double-quotes - `"` - for identifiers ...

```
 SELECT
    "EC"."RSTD"
    FROM EC RIGHT JOIN EF
      ON ( "EF"."EO" = "EC"."EO" ) 
      ON ( "EF"."AC" = "EC"."AC" ) 
      ON ( "EF"."PN" = "EC"."PN" ) 
      ON ( "EF"."PSN' = "EC"."PSN" )
```

... or, even better, omit them altogether:

```
 SELECT
    EC.RSTD
    FROM EC RIGHT JOIN EF
      ON ( EF.EO = EC.EO ) 
      ON ( EF.AC = EC.AC ) 
      ON ( EF.PN = EC.PN ) 
      ON ( EF.PSN = EC.PSN )
```

Obviously keep the single quotes when appropriate e.g. comparing a column to a literal:

```
where EO.WB = 'Y'
```

Also note that it is unnecessary to use a column alias when you're not changing the column name: `select ec.rstd as rstd` is redundant, and indeed annoying. Reserve their use for renaming columns e.g. `select ec.rstd as my_new_col_name`